# How to replace a Request value after a specific pattern in text file?

Tags: xml, bash, shell, unix, sed

Solaris , VERSION: 11.10.0,REV=2005.01.21.15.53
I have a file `test.txt` which contains values like below:

```
 <Info>
     <AccountNumber>23456789</AccountNumber>
     <BranchNumber>004</BranchNumber>
     <TransitNumber>01646</TransitNumber>
     <NameAndCity>XYZ Bank</NameAndCity>
     <OwnerFullName>ABC XYZ</OwnerFullName>
  </Info>
```

All the info is in a line and we have multiple lines like above also other tags are available.

It contains other tag values as well. Also if the tag values contains "333" combination, I don't want to replace them.

I want to use sed command to replace value of the tag with 33333 and after replacement, I want to save the updated info to same file.
Output should be :

```
 <Info>
     <AccountNumber>33333333</AccountNumber>
     <BranchNumber>33333</BranchNumber>
     <TransitNumber>3333333</TransitNumber>
     <NameAndCity>333 33333</NameAndCity>
     <OwnerFullName>3333 33333</OwnerFullName>
  </Info>
```

I am new to shell script and not exactly able to write the pattern to match it.

Here is what i have implemented so far to first two tag values but it is not working:

```
sed 's/(<AccountNumber>)\+[0-2,4-9]*$/\1 33333333/' test.txt
sed 's/(<BranchNumber>)\+[0-2,4-9]*$/\1 33333/' test.txt
```

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Actual tags are :                                      <AccountNumber>2345678</AccountNumber>

<BankBranchNumber>234</BankBranchNumber>

Comment: thanks Tiw, Updated

Comment: Ahh... I thought you only want to replace two tags, but after edit I see you want to replace values in all the tags?

Comment: Solaris , VERSION:  11.10.0,REV=2005.01.21.15.53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -e '/333/!{' -e 's#<AccountNumber>[0-9]*</AccountNumber>#<AccountNumber>333333333</AccountNumber>#;s#<BranchNumber>[0-9]*</BranchNumber>#<BranchNumber>33333</BranchNumber>#;}'
```

Eg:

```
$ sed -e '/333/!{' -e 's#<AccountNumber>[0-9]*</AccountNumber>#<AccountNumber>333333333</AccountNumber>#;s#<BranchNumber>[0-9]*</BranchNumber>#<BranchNumber>33333</BranchNumber>#;}'  test.txt
 <Info>
     <AccountNumber>333333333</AccountNumber>
     <BranchNumber>33333</BranchNumber>
     <TransitNumber>01646</TransitNumber>
     <NameAndCity>XYZ Bank</NameAndCity>
     <OwnerFullName>ABC XYZ</OwnerFullName>
  </Info>
```

A very straightforward way, if you test ok and want to change the file inplace, add `-i` switch.

I don't have Solaris to test, so can't be sure.

Try this simple `perl` one see if it's working:

```
perl -pe 's#<AccountNumber>[0-9]*</AccountNumber>#<AccountNumber>333333333</AccountNumber>#' test.txt
```

If it's working, we can add others.

So for your logic first wrote in the question, it should be like this:

```
perl -pe 'unless (/333/) {s#<AccountNumber>[0-9]*</AccountNumber>#<AccountNumber>333333333</AccountNumber>#;s#<BranchNumber>[0-9]*</BranchNumber>#<BranchNumber>33333</BranchNumber>#;}' test.txt
```

You can add other substitudes yourself. the `#` is to replace the usual `/` of `s`, an easier way to avoid escape the `/` in close tags (I.E. `s#from#to#;`).
It's rather straightforward so I think you'll have no difficulty :)
Add `-i` switch to change inplace, like this: `perl -i -pe '...`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file.txt 
<Info>
    <AccountNumber>23456789</AccountNumber>
    <BranchNumber>004</BranchNumber>
    <TransitNumber>01646</TransitNumber>
    <NameAndCity>XYZ Bank</NameAndCity>
    <OwnerFullName>ABC XYZ</OwnerFullName>
</Info>
<Info>
    <AccountNumber>23456789</AccountNumber>
    <BranchNumber>004</BranchNumber>
    <TransitNumber>01646</TransitNumber>
    <NameAndCity>333 Bank</NameAndCity>
    <OwnerFullName>ABC XYZ</OwnerFullName>
</Info>

$ sed -r '/.*333 /!s#^(\s*<[^>]+>).*(</[^>]+>)$#\133333\2#;s|^(\s*<[^>]+>333 ).*(</[^>]+>)$|\133333\2|' file.txt
<Info>
    <AccountNumber>33333</AccountNumber>
    <BranchNumber>33333</BranchNumber>
    <TransitNumber>33333</TransitNumber>
    <NameAndCity>33333</NameAndCity>
    <OwnerFullName>33333</OwnerFullName>
</Info>
<Info>
    <AccountNumber>33333</AccountNumber>
    <BranchNumber>33333</BranchNumber>
    <TransitNumber>33333</TransitNumber>
    <NameAndCity>333 33333</NameAndCity>
    <OwnerFullName>33333</OwnerFullName>
</Info>
```

First negate strings which have `">333 "` in them with `/.*333 /!`. Such strings will be affected by the second regex `s#^(\s*<[^>]+>).*(</[^>]+>)$#\133333\2#;`. Strings that do have `">333 "` in them will be changed according `s|^(\s*<[^>]+>333 ).*(</[^>]+>)$|\133333\2|`.

Add the -i option to sed to apply the changes.

EDIT:

As @Tiw commented, it is better to use perl instead of sed:

```
$ perl -pe 's#<([^>]+)>(?:(?!333).)*</\1>#<\1>333333333<\1>#;s#<([^>]+)>333 .*#<\1>333 3333</\1>#' -i file.txt
<Info>
    <AccountNumber>333333333<AccountNumber>
    <BranchNumber>333333333<BranchNumber>
    <TransitNumber>333333333<TransitNumber>
    <NameAndCity>333333333<NameAndCity>
    <OwnerFullName>333333333<OwnerFullName>
</Info>
<Info>
    <AccountNumber>333333333<AccountNumber>
    <BranchNumber>333333333<BranchNumber>
    <TransitNumber>333333333<TransitNumber>
    <NameAndCity>333 3333</NameAndCity>
    <OwnerFullName>333333333<OwnerFullName>
</Info>
```

Note: the -i option applies the changes to the file.

Comment: $ sed -r '/.*333 /!s#^(\s*<[^>]+>).*(</[^>]+>)$#\133333\2#;s|^(\s*<[^>]+>333 ).*(</[^>]+>)$|\133333\2|' test.txt
                 sed: illegal option -- r                                                                                            @Bayou

Comment: @minkuJha Ah, I see [man sed](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/sed-1.html). In gnu-sed, the -r option enables extended regex. According to [man regex](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29043/regex-5.html#scrolltoc) you already have back references. Could try it without the -r option instead?

Comment: I tried with -r as well but same Result :                                                                                    $ sed -r '/.*333 /!s#^(\s*<[^>]+>).*(</[^>]+>)$#\133333\2#;s|^(\s*<[^>]+>333 ).*(</[^>]+>)$|\133333\2|' test.txt                                                                                              
  sed: illegal option -- r                                                                          @Bayou

Comment: That's correct @Tiw , Solaris is not having gnu-sed

Comment: @minkuJha You haven't removed the `-r` option between sed and the regex. You will get something like `sed "<regex>" <file>`.

Comment: $  sed '/.*333 /!s#^(\s*<[^>]+>).*(</[^>]+>)$#\133333\2#;s|^(\s*<[^>]+>333 ).*(</[^>]+>)$|\133333\2|' test.txt
sed: command garbled: /.*333 /!s#^(\s*<[^>]+>).*(</[^>]+>)$#\133333\2#;s|^(\s*<[^>]+>333 ).*(</[^>]+>)$|\133333\2|
@Bayou

Answer (score 1):

Posting with the all correct details for future users :

```
perl -pe 's#<([^>]+)>(?:(?!333).)*</\1>#<\1>333333333<\1>#;s#<([^>]+)>333 .*#<\1>333 3333</\1>#' -i file.txt
```

Above will Replace all the tag value with 333333333 even that's not AccountNumber, BranchNumber..etc tags, it will replace other tags values as well .  also  NameAndCity and OwnerFullName are alphanumeric so we need to add Regex with alphanumeric/special/space for those .                                                           Here is answer :

```
perl -i -pe 'unless (/333/) {s#<AccountNumber>[0-9]*</AccountNumber>#<AccountNumber>33333333</AccountNumber>#;
        s#<BranchNumber>[0-9]*</BranchNumber>#<BranchNumber>33333</BranchNumber>#;
        s#<TransitNumber>[0-9]*</TransitNumber>#<TransitNumber>3333333</TransitNumber>#;
        s#<NameAndCity>[A-Za-z\ \-\+]*</NameAndCity>#<NameAndCity>333 33333</NameAndCity>#;
        s#<OwnerFullName>[A-Za-z/\/\ \+]*</OwnerFullName>#<OwnerFullName>3333 33333</OwnerFullName>#;}' test.txt
```

Comment: @Tiw , can you accept my answer for future reference . found  few issue so added the modified with all the details.